# SparkPi - unable to find valid certification path

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I'm downloaded "spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3-scala2.13" from official website and now trying to submit "SparkPi" example app to my local k8s cluster (rancher-desktop).

Pod is created, app runs for few seconds and crushes. Info below.

My command:

```
spark-submit.cmd --master k8s://https://172.17.45.59:6443 --deploy-mode cluster --name spark-pi --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --conf spark.executor.instances=2 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark:our-own-apache-spark-kb8 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=IfNotPresent --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.13-3.5.1.jar 100
```

Pod logs:

```
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2888)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:1099)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:1093)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi$.main(SparkPi.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi.main(SparkPi.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1029)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1129)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterManager.makeExecutorPodsAllocator(KubernetesClusterManager.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterManager.createSchedulerBackend(KubernetesClusterManager.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:3203)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [Pod]  with name: [spark-pi-183d9a8e15e3ffc0-driver]  in namespace: [default]  failed.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:159)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.requireFromServer(BaseOperation.java:187)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:141)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:92)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator.$anonfun$driverPod$1(ExecutorPodsAllocator.scala:96)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator.<init>(ExecutorPodsAllocator.scala:94)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.waitForResult(OperationSupport.java:515)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:535)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:478)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:741)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.requireFromServer(BaseOperation.java:185)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:320)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:284)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:169)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:258)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:127)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:257)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 40 more
24/03/06 22:30:57 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
24/03/06 22:30:57 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-ab5cefa4-3a66-4e52-a3ec-eaf14d892f4d
24/03/06 22:30:57 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /var/data/spark-14659837-7421-4a08-95be-d842cbd3cf42/spark-caf9b167-d322-4ded-af79-5dbfa1350c8c
Stream closed EOF for default/spark-pi-183d9a8e15e3ffc0-driver (spark-kubernetes-driver)
```

If anyone has any idea what might be the cause and how to fix that, please let me know. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there was an issue with "spark" service account permissions, I've tried to add cluster admin role for this account but it didn't help (same error).

Finally solved this by removing "--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark" from spark-submit command and then adding "cluster-admin" permissions for all service accounts in default namespace, like this:

```
kubectl create rolebinding default-all-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --group=system:serviceaccounts:default --namespace=default
```

With these changes "SparkPi" executes successfully.